# Cypher Editor does not link to Database Graph in Neoclipse

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neoclipse

I am running neoclipse-1.9.1-win32.win32.x86_64, which I downloaded last week. In the Database Graph tab,I can see the root node and extend to other nodes by clicking the "+" button. In the Cypher Editor tab, I can execute the Cypher query

`start root=node(0), l=node(100) match root-[:Branch]-n-[:ObjCol]-m-[r]-l return root, l;`

and see the results in the "Results" sub tab. But when I switch back to the Database Graph tab, it does not automatically show the nodes and pathes as the executed Cypher query.

What I need to do to make the Cypher query executed in the Cypher Editor tab to show up in the Database Graph tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph tab doesn't sync with the query you have executed from the Cypher editor tab. You can however configure the depth of the graph through `Options > Neo4j > Maximum Traversal Depth`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize your query results, you can start neo4j in server mode and use the server console.